# UI freezes on executing NSBatchDeleteRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [Report fetchRequest];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"reportId IN %@",self.selectedRowsInEditMode];

NSBatchDeleteRequest *deleteDetailsRequest = [[NSBatchDeleteRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request];
deleteDetailsRequest.resultType = NSBatchDeleteResultTypeStatusOnly;
[self.managedObjectContext executeRequest:deleteDetailsRequest error:&errorExecuteRequest];

if (!errorExecuteRequest) {
    NSError *deleteSaveError;
    BOOL saveSuccessful = [self.managedObjectContext save:&deleteSaveError];
    [self.tableView removeLoadingActivityView];
```

This is the code where in I am trying to delete multiple report managed objects at once but when executeRequest is called the UI freezes for quite a while and then deletes. But NSBatchDeleteRequest is supposed to be very quick in terms of deletion. I tried multiple modifications to get it working but with no success.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. So could anyone pls suggest to get it working without UI glitch.

Comment: Can you enable SQLDebug and post the console output.  It should show some detail about the SQL requests being processed to fulfil the batch delete.

Comment: Do you know roughly how large is your database and roughly how many objects you are deleting?

Also is your batch delete request executing on the main thread? (I guess so, if it is freezing the UI)

Comment: @frankodwyer I had code on main queue earlier, then i moved it a separate background queue. So that is resolved but my concern as NSBatchDeleteRequest taking sometime to delete even request to delete single entity. The entity has has a relationship object with nullify rule. Even if I have a single relationship obj then as well its taking time.

Comment: @pbasdf Cannot post console log of DB as I cannot share data info.

Comment: @pbasdf I can just say I have couple of relationships w.r.t entity object I am using here. But even if I have just a single relationship object in only one of relationship also its taking time. 
But I would like to know in general how does NSBathcDeleteRequest behave ?

Comment: The point of the batchDeleteRequest is that it operates directly at the database level, deleting records directly from the relevant SQLite table.  Before NSBatchDeleteRequest, to delete many objects you had to fetch them all and then delete each one.  The reason for this was so that CD could update all the relevant relationships, to ensure you weren’t left with referential integrity problems.  To achieve the same, NSBatchDeleteRequests set up SQLite triggers which nullify the references to any deleted objects.....

Comment: .... It would be interesting to know whether the time is spent on the main delete request (and associated table search) or the subsequent trigger processing.  Incidentally, is reportId indexed, to speed up the main table search?

Comment: @pbasdf Any references on debugging using sqlite would help.

Comment: @frankodwyer I did check console log with debug flag on,  I see CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0309s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0311s for 0 rows.
multiple times with diff execution times.. there is a relationship from Report managed object I am trying to delete. this RelationShip object has 3-4 relationships inturn.. so I think its trying to fetch all those relationships in turn.. How can this be avoided ?

Comment: @pbasdf any solns  w.r.t comment above ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope will helpful to you following code!!

I ended up adding the following to take care of the context after the batch delete.

```
[self.managedObjectContext refreshAllObjects];

// Initialize Fetch Request
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [Report fetchRequest];

// Add Sort Descriptors
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"reportId IN %@",self.selectedRowsInEditMode];

// Initialize Asynchronous Fetch Request
NSAsynchronousFetchRequest *asynchronousFetchRequest = [[NSAsynchronousFetchRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest completionBlock:^(NSAsynchronousFetchResult *result) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Process Asynchronous Fetch Result
        [weakSelf processAsynchronousFetchResult:result];
    });
}];

// Execute Asynchronous Fetch Request
[self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    // Execute Asynchronous Fetch Request
    NSError *asynchronousFetchRequestError = nil;
    NSAsynchronousFetchResult *asynchronousFetchResult = (NSAsynchronousFetchResult *)[weakSelf.managedObjectContext executeRequest:asynchronousFetchRequest error:&asynchronousFetchRequestError];

    if (asynchronousFetchRequestError) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to execute asynchronous fetch result.");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", asynchronousFetchRequestError, asynchronousFetchRequestError.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

Or using below you use the global queue to run things in the background and the main queue to update the UI

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the information but I wanted to have a solution or suggestion why the batch delete is taking so much time. Want to know if I am doing anything wrong for batch delete to take so much time.. Asynchronous fetch request would be last approach with a indicator for user about deletion in progress. But would like to know if any approach to prevent BatchDeleteRequest to take so much time

Comment: using this line code [self.managedObjectContext refreshAllObjects]; hope will help you!

Comment: refresh before execution of batchdeleterequest ?

Comment: Yes use before execution of batchdeleterequest

Comment: You mentioned "I ended up adding the following to take care of the context after the batch delete."
So do you mean to add code you mentioned above after calling execute:(BatchRequest) ?
If so then issue I am facing not after calling execute:(BatchRequest) but issue is with execute:(BatchRequest) itself taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Asynchronous Fetch Request, the synchronous can freeze the UI. This link [Asynchronous Fetch Request](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-asynchronous-fetching--cms-22241) is a tutorial in objective C that explain how.